# How can I loop into the objects of a DTO in Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to GET all players from a list, but the whole GetMapping it's constructed around Player DTO. The data I want to loop is a list of "players" stored into a DTO like this:

```
{
    PLAYERS: [
        { player0 {parameters...} },
        { player1 {parameters...} },
        ...
    ]
}
```

Here is my ajax code in JS:

```
//GET ALL PLAYERS

function getAllPlayers() {

    document.getElementById("erase_repeated_results").innerHTML = ""; //to erase info I don't want to store
    document.getElementById("fullInfo").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("sameRoles").innerHTML = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8081/dices/players",
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {

                document.getElementById("fullInfo").innerHTML += "Complete info of player " + (j+1) + ": " + "<br />" + "<br />" +
                    "The ID of this player is: " + data[j].id + "<br />" +
                    "The name of this player is: " + data[j].name + "<br />" +
                    "The register date of this player is: " + data[j].registerDate + "<br />" +
                    "The total amount of dice rolls of this player is: " + data[j].totalDiceRolls + "<br />" +
                    "The total amount of games won of this player is: " + data[j].gamesWon + "<br />" +
                    "The success rate of this player is: " + data[j].successRate + "<br />";

                console.log(data[j]);
            }
        },
        error: function () {

            alert("Something went wrong! Maybe you are entering parameters not related to our Database!");
        }
    });
}
```

Below I attached a screenshot so you can see how it is working while I debug it, and you'll see in the scope section what I'm talking about.

How can I enter only in the array parameter of the DTO?

[image]

Comment: Code is text. Please post your code as text, not a screenshot. The How To Ask page in the help section specifically mentions not to post images of your code, they are unhelpful to the people trying to answer. Please update your question to get a more positive response. Thanks.

Comment: @ADyson sorry, I added only the image because I thought it has more useful info than just the code, now I added my code of ajax too, thanks!

Comment: ok thanks. I will add an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your data structure, it's the `PLAYERS` property which is an array. `data` is an object containing a single property called `PLAYERS`. So looping through that makes no sense. Just loop through the players array instead:

```
for (var j = 0; j < data.PLAYERS.length; j++) {
  document.getElementById("fullInfo").innerHTML += "Complete info of player " + (j+1) + ": " + "<br />" + "<br />" +
      "The ID of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].id + "<br />" +
      "The name of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].name + "<br />" +
      "The register date of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].registerDate + "<br />" +
      "The total amount of dice rolls of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].totalDiceRolls + "<br />" +
      "The total amount of games won of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].gamesWon + "<br />" +
      "The success rate of this player is: " + data.PLAYERS[j].successRate + "<br />";

  console.log(data.PLAYERS[j]);
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you! I thought that PLAYERS was only a regular String as in my DTO it is just that and the second parameter in DTO was the array itself. So therefore the first parameter String of a DTO it's not working only as string right?

Comment: I have one more question, if PLAYERS is the 'name' of the array, How I could do the same as you posted but with an array that changes its name? Let me explain, now I am doing the same you did here but with the 'games' of each player, and it's also a DTO of games, so every player has its own array of games like that: `{
    PETER: [
        { game0{parameters...} },
        { game1{parameters...} },
        ...
    ]
}` .....

Comment: .... ... so depending on its ID I can GET one user or another. I don't know if that's the correct way to work with DTOs because now I realize that maybe the best solution is just to substitute their names as the main name of the DTO array and just giving that info INTO the array. I hope I explained it well... sorry for my English and thanks!

Comment: "How I could do the same as you posted but with an array that changes its name"...actually my recommendation would be not to generate a dataset which has an unpredictable structure. As you are predicting, this will start to cause you a headache when writing code to process it. Instead I would probably output a single array of games, and have the player's name (or ID) as a property of each game object in the array. That way you can tell who each game belongs to, and you can write code to filter the data to show only the games for a specific player if you need to.

Comment: Yes I did it like that already and the API is almost finished and working perfectly. Thank you for all your knowledge!